# Extracting Data from DataGrid into Binded Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

What I am trying to do is take the string out of a specific column in my DataGrid and display that string in the Combobox.Text property. I am using this code to do so:

```
var dataString = ((DataRowView)dgvMain.SelectedItem).Row["Column"].ToString();
```

I have placed a breakpoint on this to see what it was pulling, and it was the correct String that is contained as an item in the Combobox, but whenever I try to set it via Combobox.Text, the Combobox is empty. I have however set my Combobox to isEditable = True and ReadOnly = True and this method works, but selecting an item in the Collection will display System.Data.DataRowView, due to the Combobox being binded to my DataTable. I'll add the XAML to my Combobox as well:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboAlarmType" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="138,256,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="320" TabIndex="5"
              BorderBrush="Black" Background="White" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="AlarmName" SelectedValuePath="AlarmName" 
              SelectedValue="{Binding Row.Column, ElementName=dgvMain}"/>
```

This method works in Textboxes and Checkboxes, but haven't seemed to figure it out for Comboboxes. Any guidance would be appreciated! :)

Comment: How are you populating your DataGrid? In WPF, you don't need to do ugly stuff like this. Just go to the items you're using to populate the DataGrid. Also, that multibinding in your DataTemplate looks like guesswork; you don't seem to be doing anything a multibinding would ever be used for. What are you populating the combobox with?

Comment: I'm filling the DataGrid via a DataTable. The data in the DataTable is from a Select statement from my SQLite database.

Comment: `<DataTemplate><TextBlock Text="{Binding Column}" /></DataTemplate>` should do the same as what you've got there.

Comment: I guess the reason I left Multibinding StringFormat in there was because I was combining 2 columns at one time. You're right, it wouldn't be necessary for just one column.

Comment: Oh, so `DataRowView` is a row in the datatable, sorry (derp). Is the ComboBox populating? I think what you want may be `<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Column" SelectedValuePath="Column" SelectedValue="{Binding Row.Column, ElementName=dgvMain}" ... />`

Comment: ...and leave out the ItemTemplate, if you're just displaying one column. /// Ahh OK, gotcha re: multibinding.

Comment: The Combobox is populating the same was as the DataGrid, just with different data from SQL. But your solution has solved this! Is there anyway I can get this data to display on launch? I am currently setting the SelectedIndex of the DataGrid once everything has loaded, in return fires the DataGrid's SelectionChanged event. It seems to skip the Combobox, but if I select something myself, it works.

Comment: That will be much, much simpler if you are using a viewmodel that has the DataTable as a public property. Like, falling off a log simple (N.B. we don't have a log here in my office to test that assumption, but trust me, it's simple).

Comment: Haha thanks, i'm going to look into it.

Comment: I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that your `DataContext` for the `ComboBox` must be the `DataTable` you're using to populate the `DataGrid`, because `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`. I'm going to assume that it's the `DataContext` for the `DataGrid` as well, and that your goal is to have the `ComboBox` selection reflect the selected row in the `DataGrid`.

```
<DataGrid
    x:Name="dgvMain"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    />
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Column"
    SelectedValuePath="Column"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem.Row[Column], ElementName=dgvMain}"
    />
```

If you'd like the selection changes to go both ways -- so a change to the `ComboBox` selection changes the `DataGrid` selection -- that's easy:

```
<DataGrid
    x:Name="dgvMain"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    SelectedValuePath="Column"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=ColumnComboBox}"
    />
<ComboBox
    x:Name="ColumnComboBox"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Column"
    SelectedValuePath="Column"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem.Row[Column], ElementName=dgvMain}"
    />
```

And here's a cleaner way to do the whole thing:
First, write a viewmodel class in C#.

```
public class ViewModelbase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class MyViewModel : ViewModelbase
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        //  I populated my DataTable with "Row 1", "Row 2", etc.
        //  Naturally you'd use a value from your own data. 
        SelectedColumnValue = "Row 2";
    }

    #region SelectedColumnValue Property
    private String _selectedColumnValue = default(String);
    public String SelectedColumnValue
    {
        get { return _selectedColumnValue; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedColumnValue)
            {
                _selectedColumnValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion SelectedColumnValue Property

    public DataTable Data { get; protected set; }
}
```

Then use that `SelectedColumnValue` property to keep track of the selected value of "Column" for both controls. The bindings on the `SelectedValue` properties of the two controls will be two-way by default, because of framework stuff that makes it be that way (how's that for an explanation?). So if you change `SelectedColumnValue` programatically, the controls will update, and if the user changes the grid selection, the viewmodel property will be updated, which will in turn update the `ComboBox` -- and vice versa.

```
<DataGrid
    ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
    SelectedValuePath="Column"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedColumnValue}"
    />
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Column"
    SelectedValuePath="Column"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedColumnValue}"
    />
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
    DisplayMemberPath="ShoeSize"
    SelectedValuePath="Column"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedColumnValue}"
    />
```

Another wrinkle is that `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` needn't be the same. Say we've got a "ShoeSize" column in `Data`, and we'd like to have those values displayed in another `ComboBox`. So we can do that. We're still using `Column` as a unique identifier for rows in `Data`, but we can tell the `ComboBox` to display some other column.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Is it good practice to keep all XAML properties to one per line, or is that just preference?

Comment: @RockGuitarist1 If an element has more than one or two attributes, I find it much more readable, especially on StackOverflow where the formatting gives you such a narrow view of the code. Horizontal scrolling is hard on the reader.

Comment: Probably a good idea then. I have 8 Comboxes to do this for, so i'll have to look up a way to have multiple SelectedValuePaths and SelectedValues in the DataGrid's XAML.

Comment: @RockGuitarist1 You can't. It's only got one. What you *can* do is have multiple combos that all have a `SelectedValuePath="Column", but `DisplayMemberPath` that's a different column in the `DataTable`.

Comment: @RockGuitarist1 Added that to the answer.

Comment: I have 2 columns called First Name and Last Name in the DataGrid that concatenate into 6 of my Comboboxes, that's why I was using the MultiBinding StringFormat. I guess this wouldn't work with a viewmodel?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125612/discussion-between-ed-plunkett-and-rockguitarist1).